# Click a link to download file using curl

Tags: curl

I have an HTML page on which several links are there, I want to click one link and that will download relevant file for me. How do I simulate this using curl.
All links have different name attribute

Comment: Wait, you want to click a link, and have that link downloaded with `curl`? Why? I mean, it might be doable through browser modification, but I don't know why you would want that.

Comment: I dint get the meaning of browser modification, I just need to do this using cURL script

Comment: So… you don't want to click the link, you just want to do this in a shell script?

Comment: Also, can you show us the web page? With what you've said so far, I don't believe your question will garner helpful responses.

Comment: OK.It does not look possible. But i have seen some examples of cURL where we can put values on different input fields and click a submit button using cURL. So I thought there must be some way to click a link too

Comment: Can you give us an example, or a tutorial, or something? What you're posting (at least, to me) doesn't really make much sense. `curl` is a command-line utility. It can be used by graphical utilities, but then we would need to know which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click a link in a browser it creates a http request with not only the path to the link but information such as to the identity of the browser, language, cookies and many other values the server may choose to use(or ignore).

This ignores the fact that the page may use javascript to react to the click.

curl will allow you generate a complete http request with all the same values as if it was created by the browser. Bottom line is the server will not be able to tell a well crafted curl request from a browser.

curl the command line utility does not interact directly with GUI applications like web browsers.

curl capabilities extends far beyond just sending http requests. I use it mainly to fake calls to web services from mobile apps.

You might like to also look at libcurl http://curl.haxx.se/ which could be added to other products that could interact with other apps.